# How to add Julia to path in WSL2?

Tags: linux, path, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I ran these commands in my ~ directory according to a tutorial:

```
wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.6/julia-1.6.2-linux- 
x86_64.tar.gz
tar zxvf julia-1.6.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
sudo mv -r julia-1.6.2 /opt/
```

For some reason, symlink isn't working so I want to add to the path instead.

To add Julia's bin folder (with full path) to PATH environment variable, you can edit the ~/.bashrc (or ~/.bash_profile) file. Open the file in your favourite editor and add a new line as follows:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/<Julia directory>/bin"
```

This is what I tried but it does not work. I already have a PATH for CUDA and tried to append to end of that one.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:/opt/julia-1.6.2/bin/:$PATH
```

I also tried the pwd of the copy in opt and that did not work either.

```
export PATH=/usr/local/cuda/bin:/usr/local/bin/julia:$PATH
```

Comment: What's the result?  Just a normal "command not found" or something else?  The first one looks right, according to those instructions at least.

Comment: Yeah typing julia gives me a command not found, can be installed with . . . 

And trying to do a symlink with: sudo ln -s /julia-1.6.2/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
gets me a ' failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/julia': File exists'

Comment: Taking a few steps back, are you exiting the shell or `source`ing the `~/.bashrc` after adding that line so that it takes effect?  Also, what's `stat /usr/local/bin/julia` show?  I'm thinking you should just remove that one, but double-check it first.

Comment: I spent an hour with a senior engineer friend trying all sorts of stuff and we couldn't figure out why after adding it to PATH it still could not be found with `which julia`. In the end he had me do rm *julia* rm -r *julia* and from redo everything from the start and now it works.

Comment: That was definitely where I was going.  I think you created a bad link at some point that just needed to be removed.

Answer (score 0):

I could not figure out what was wrong but removing everything with the two rm commands below and then starting again worked.

```
rm *julia*

rm -r *julia*

wget https://julialang-s3.julialang.org/bin/linux/x64/1.6/julia-1.6.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz

tar -xvzf julia-1.6.2-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
```

These two lines below are optional, just to check that running it works.

```
cd julia-1.6.2/bin

./julia
```

This is below is how to set the symlink so you can run julia by typing just julia and not julia-1.6.2/bin/julia.

```
cd ~

sudo cp -r julia-1.6.2 /opt/

sudo ln -s /opt/julia-1.6.2/bin/julia /usr/local/bin/julia
```